# Filtering a Database in Jetpack Compose: Not Working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

so I have a suspend function, i am calling from a coroutine, with filter-criteria.
This filter-criteria is then being passed to the viewmodel, to a query more specifically.
All of this is stored in a ui-state, which is being utilized in my Mainscreen using ".collectasState()". Based on if the filter is activated, the collected entities stored in the ui-state, are being displayed in a LazyColumn. The problem is, nothing happens when i execute the filter, it always shows what it would normally show(the entities from the database, unfiltered).
When i try to print it out, to see if there are entities being filtered, i get this:

2023-12-17 19:58:39.316  9995-9995  FilterListComplete      com.example.myapplication            D  Filtered Results: []

I would very appreciate it, if someone could tell me what im doing wrong here!

**This is my Viewmodel:**

```
class FilterProductViewModel(private val productRepository: ProductRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var _filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> = MutableStateFlow(FilterProductUiState())
    val filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> get() = _filterProductUiState

    private var isFilterActive = false

    fun isFilterActive(): Boolean {
        return isFilterActive
    }

    suspend fun applyProductFilter(

        category: List<Category?>,
        currency: String,
        startPrice: Double,
        endPrice: Double,
        startDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        company: String
    ) {
        isFilterActive = true

        val _filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> = productRepository.filterProducts(
            category = category,
            currency = currency,
            startPrice = startPrice,
            endPrice = endPrice,
            startDate = startDate,
            endDate = endDate,
            company = company
        ).map { FilterProductUiState(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = FilterProductUiState()
            )

        Log.d("FilterListComplete", "Filtered Results: ${filterProductUiState.value}")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L
    }



}

data class FilterProductUiState(val filterProductList: List<Product> = listOf())
```

**And this is my Query in my DAO:**

```
        "SELECT * FROM Product " +
                "WHERE category IN (:categoryList) " +
                "AND currency = :currency " +
                "AND price >= :startPrice " +
                "AND price <= :endPrice " +
                "AND date >= :startDate " +
                "AND date <= :endDate " +
                "AND company = :company " +
                "ORDER BY category DESC"
    )


    fun filterProducts(
        categoryList: List<Category?>,
        currency: String?,
        startPrice: Double?,
        endPrice: Double?,
        startDate: String?,
        endDate: String?,
        company: String?
    ): Flow<List<Product>>
```

EDIT:

```
class FilterProductViewModel(private val productRepository: ProductRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var _filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> = MutableStateFlow(FilterProductUiState())
    val filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> get() = _filterProductUiState

    private var isFilterActive = false

    fun isFilterActive(): Boolean {
        return isFilterActive
    }

    suspend fun applyProductFilter(
        category: List<Category?>,
        currency: String,
        startPrice: Double,
        endPrice: Double,
        startDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        company: String
    ) {
        isFilterActive = true

        private val filteredProducts: StateFlow<List<FilterProductUiState>> = productRepository.filterProducts(
            category = category,
            currency = currency,
            startPrice = startPrice,
            endPrice = endPrice,
            startDate = startDate,
            endDate = endDate,
            company = company
        ).stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
            initialValue = FilterProductUiState()
        )

        val filterProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> = filteredProducts.transformLatest { FilterProductUiState(it) }

        Log.d("FilterListComplete", "Filtered Results: ${filterProductUiState.value}")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L
    }



}

data class FilterProductUiState(val filterProductList: List<Product> = listOf())
```

Answer (score 0):

In `applyProductFilter()` you are not updating the variable `_filterProductUiState` of the Viewmodel, you are creating a new variable locale to the method scope as you are defining it inside it as `val _filterProductUiState`. In order to replace it you would need to reassign it without `val` upfront. But in this case there would also be an issue: if your UI collects the initial StateFlow it will not collect the second one (at least right away, not sure if the recomposition will resubscribe to the new instance) as it has changed of instance.

Edit:

```
class FilterProductViewModel(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _filteredProducts: MutableStateFlow<List<Product>> =
        MutableStateFlow(emptyList())

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val filterProductUiState: Flow<FilterProductUiState> =
        _filteredProducts.transformLatest { FilterProductUiState(it) }

    private var isFilterActive = false
    private var filterJob: Job? = null

    fun isFilterActive(): Boolean {
        return isFilterActive
    }

    suspend fun applyProductFilter(
        category: List<Category?>,
        currency: String,
        startPrice: Double,
        endPrice: Double,
        startDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        company: String
    ) {
        isFilterActive = true

        filterJob?.cancel()

        filterJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            productRepository.filterProducts(
                category = category,
                currency = currency,
                startPrice = startPrice,
                endPrice = endPrice,
                startDate = startDate,
                endDate = endDate,
                company = company
            ).collect {
                _filterProductUiState.update { it }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, unfortunately i get some errors. is this version of the code, how you intended it? Please have a look at the code above unde "EDIT"